# Launch Image Picker from button not working

Tags: ios

I am using the standard tab bar application as a basis for a test app.

I am also trying to use the ELCAlbumPickerController class found at github.

The button to launch the photo picker and the uiscrollview are located in the Secondview.xib

The following is the code in the SecondViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ELCImagePickerController.h"


@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController       <ELCImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate>{
    UIWindow *window;
    SecondViewController *viewController;
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollview;

}

@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet SecondViewController *viewController;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollview;

-(IBAction)launchController;

@end
```

And the following is in SecondViewController.m

```
#import "myappAppDelegate.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"
#import "ELCImagePickerController.h"
#import "ELCAlbumPickerController.h"

@implementation SecondViewController

@synthesize window;
@synthesize viewController;
@synthesize scrollview;


/*
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from  a nib.*/
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    //[self launchController:self];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:  (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

-(IBAction)launchController {

    ELCAlbumPickerController *albumController = [[ELCAlbumPickerController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ELCAlbumPickerController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];    
    ELCImagePickerController *elcPicker = [[ELCImagePickerController alloc] initWithRootViewController:albumController];
    [albumController setParent:elcPicker];
    [elcPicker setDelegate:self];

    //myappAppDelegate *app = (myappAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    SecondViewController *app = (SecondViewController *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [app.viewController presentModalViewController:elcPicker animated:YES];
    [elcPicker release];
    [albumController release];
}

#pragma mark ELCImagePickerControllerDelegate Methods

- (void)elcImagePickerController:(ELCImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSArray *)info {

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    for (UIView *v in [scrollview subviews]) {
    [v removeFromSuperview];
    }

CGRect workingFrame = scrollview.frame;
workingFrame.origin.x = 0;

for(NSDictionary *dict in info) {

    UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]];
    [imageview setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    imageview.frame = workingFrame;

    [scrollview addSubview:imageview];
    [imageview release];

    workingFrame.origin.x = workingFrame.origin.x + workingFrame.size.width;
}

[scrollview setPagingEnabled:YES];
[scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(workingFrame.origin.x,   workingFrame.size.height)];
}

 - (void)elcImagePickerControllerDidCancel:(ELCImagePickerController *)picker {

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc. that aren't in use.
}


- (void)viewDidUnload
   {
    [super viewDidUnload];

    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
    }


- (void)dealloc
{ 
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

When you click the button you get a message "deallocing ELCImagePickerController" so it is calling the ELCImagePickerController class but it just does not show the image picker.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the `launchController()` method, you were casting an `appDelegate` into a `viewController`, which is logically wrong. You need to use an actual `viewController` to `presentModalViewController`. Try:

```
[self presentModalViewController:elcPicker animated:YES];
```

Comment: `presentModalViewController` is now deprecated